# How to get ranking of scores in MySQL with LIMIT?

Tags: mysql

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT id, score, username,
CASE
WHEN @prevRank = score THEN @curRank
WHEN @prevRank := score THEN @curRank := @curRank + 1
END AS rank
FROM users u,
SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL) r
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5, 5;
```

I want the next 5 ranks from row 5, but the ranking restarts at 1. How can I get the ranking to start at the correct ranking relative to all the rows?

Sample data: http://pastebin.com/i3PsRWdg

```
Everyone

+----+--------+-----------+------+
| id | scores | username  | rank |
+----+--------+-----------+------+
| 24 |     23 | fl        |    1 |
|  3 |      9 | test      |    2 |
|  6 |      9 | usernine  |    2 |
|  5 |      7 | test3     |    3 |
| 11 |      7 | test9     |    3 |
| 26 |      5 | tryagain  |    4 |
| 12 |      5 | newUser   |    4 |
|  7 |      3 | test6     |    5 |
| 14 |      1 | new3      |    6 |
|  4 |      1 | test2     |    6 |
| 13 |      0 | new2      | NULL |
| 25 |      0 | newu      |    6 |
| 23 |      0 | new       |    6 |
| 22 |      0 | usernine  |    6 |
| 21 |      0 | usernine  |    6 |
| 20 |      0 | test      |    6 |
| 19 |      0 | usernine  |    6 |
| 18 |      0 | usernine  |    6 |
| 17 |      0 | usernine  |    6 |
| 15 |      0 | usernine  |    6 |
| 16 |      0 | test9     |    6 |
+----+--------+-----------+------+

LIMIT 1,5 -> correct

+----+--------+-----------+------+
| id | scores | username  | rank |
+----+--------+-----------+------+
|  3 |      9 | test      |    1 |
|  6 |      9 | usernine  |    1 |
|  5 |      7 | test3     |    2 |
| 11 |      7 | test9     |    2 |
| 26 |      5 | tryagain  |    3 |
+----+--------+-----------+------+

LIMIT 5,5 -> incorrect

+----+--------+----------+------+
| id | scores | username | rank |
+----+--------+----------+------+
| 12 |      5 | newUser  |    1 |
| 26 |      5 | usernine |    1 |
|  7 |      3 | test6    |    2 |
|  4 |      1 | test2    |    3 |
| 14 |      1 | new3     |    3 |
+----+--------+----------+------+

Should be this:

+----+--------+----------+------+
| id | scores | username | rank |
+----+--------+----------+------+
| 12 |      5 | newUser  |    4 |
| 26 |      5 | usernine |    4 |
|  7 |      3 | test6    |    5 |
|  4 |      1 | test2    |    6 |
| 14 |      1 | new3     |    6 |
+----+--------+----------+------+
```

Comment: try using another variable `init rank` to use in the limit and in rank calculation? Not sure if mysql would allow it

Comment: Will help a lot if you include a sample data and desire output. To me isnt clear what is the result you want

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza http://pastebin.com/i3PsRWdg

Comment: @Sebas I think it would, but the issue is that some users have the same scores, so I wouldn't know the initial score.

Comment: how you got a null rank in your pastebing sample?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to solve an issue at the wrong level. Your database does not think in rows, it thinks in datasets. It's world consists of neat rectangular tables, not rows or fields. The whole concept of 'adding per row' that you employ with the `@curRank` hack actually doesn't work in SQL Server for example because it correctly treats the whole set as an atomic entity.

Which brings us back to that your problem is architectural, not database related. The database is just responsible for storing, organizing, aggregating and returning data. Numbering the rows most certainly isn't, it belongs in either your business logic or your presentation logic.

To solve it in the business logic, which is where you'll be feeding the `5` offset to this query to begin with, you could store the resulting rows in a numbered array. In the presentation layer of a website for example, you would use an ordered list like `<ol start="6">`.

Comment: So you're saying that I should calculate the whole thing, place it in an array, then choose the correct ones when needed?

Comment: I partially disagree, especially because I use `ROW_NUMBER()` a lot in SQL Server, and if you had that function on MySql thing like would be much easier.

Comment: @Pallas I'm saying let the database do what it's good at - storing and retrieving data. It's not good at applying vertical business logic to the data, like specifically 'comparing with previous rows and then taking an action or not'.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza `ROW_NUMBER` is still a vendor specific extension, much like `LIMIT` in MySQL itself, for solving issues that should in a perfect world be solved elsewhere. RDBMS'es should not have vertical logic.

Comment: Maybe Im confuse with your answer. But I rather solve the query in DB and return 5 rows. Than send the array to my page and sorted there.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it's fine to return 5 rows. That's a retrieval task, and one the DB is good at. Ranking them isn't. That should be done in code. Keep in mind that `ROW_NUMBER` wouldn't even help in this case, as it wouldn't be able to compare the 'current' score with the 'previous score'. The whole problem here is vertical logic, and how you should never have it in an RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one aditional variable to keep track of `row_number`

Also I use `IF()` instead of case because you version have a bug when `score = 0` produce rank `null` and didnt create `rank 7`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94e02/8)**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, score, username,
        @curRank := IF(@prevRank = score,
                       @curRank ,
                       IF(@prevRank := score,  @curRank + 1,  @curRank + 1 )
                      ) as rank,
        (@row := @row + 1) as rn
    FROM users u
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevRank := NULL, @row := 0) r
    ORDER BY score DESC
    ) T
WHERE rn >  5  
  AND rn <= 10
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id | score | username | rank | rn |
|----|-------|----------|------|----|
| 26 |     5 | tryagain |    4 |  6 |
| 12 |     5 |  newUser |    4 |  7 |
|  7 |     3 |    test6 |    5 |  8 |
| 14 |     1 |     new3 |    6 |  9 |
|  4 |     1 |    test2 |    6 | 10 |
```